# Delay between viewWillAppear and viewDidLoad after entering foreground

Tags: swift, tableview, delay, viewwillappear, viewdidappear

A delay of 2 seconds occurs between viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear only in one screen when application comes back from the background. Normally, there isn't a delay in this screen when the app is active. In debugging, it seems both viewWillAppear and viewDidAppear are completed in a few milliseconds.

In the screen, there is a horizontal scrollview of 9 pages and in each one, there is a tableview. I realized that the delay disappears when the below code of tableviews' reload is removed from viewWillAppear.

```
for i in 0 ..< self.levelTables.count {
   self.levelTables[i].tableView.reloadData()
}
```

I don't understand why this causes delay. When the app is active, there is no delay. It only appears when the application comes from the background. What's the difference? If it takes time, why is this delay not occurring always?

Any ideas?

Comment: How many tables do you have? Also, you should try using Instruments for profiling, it should help you find which function is causing the freeze.

Comment: I have 9 tables and I realized that reloading causes freeze. But why only when coming back from the background? Also, I tried putting reloading into DispatchGroup.main.async but it didn’t work. :(

Comment: The reloading itself shouldn't take too long, assuming your views aren't doing anything that they shouldn't. Find what's blocking your main thread using Instruments. If you need to learn how start here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/397-instruments-tutorial-with-swift-getting-started

Comment: Thank you very much. I've checked but I didn't get useful info. It points "main" with a self weight of 1.18s. When double click, it refers to "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate" line.